# How to Get the id of the last entity created using rest api in c#

Tags: c#

I was working on an application in .NET MAUI and I preform CRUD operations using Rest API that I created, and in some point I was Creating a `RelayCommand` that allows me to Create a new 'Supplier' buy filling in the name and etc, but I have also to select some 'sections' and I have to register those selected sections under the name of this supplier, so what I am doing is that I register them in an entity that I call `SectionSupplier` that contains both the id of the 'Supplier' and the id of the 'Section'. So I need to get the id of the Supplier I just added (using Http Post) and then for each one of those selected sections I create a new `SectionSupplier` with both the id of the resent added supplier and the id of one of the selected sections, and I came up with this method (with the help of chat gpt so it could contain something outdated or that doesn't work anymore):

```
[RelayCommand]
        public async Task CreateSupplier()
        {
            try
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(SupplierName) || SelectedSections.Count == 0)
                {
                    await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("Error", "No Field Should be empty", "Ok");
                    return;
                }

                var supplierDto = new SupplierDto()
                {
                    SupplierName = SupplierName,
                    ReturnClause = ReturnClause
                };

                var supplierJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(supplierDto);

                using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    string apiUrl = "https://localhost:7282/api/SupliersController/CreateSupplier";
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                    var response = await client.PostAsync(apiUrl, new StringContent(supplierJson, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));

                    var supplierIdJson = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    var newSupplierId = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<int>(supplierIdJson);

                    foreach (var section in SelectedSections)
                    {
                        var sectionSupplierDto = new SectionSupplierDto
                        {
                            SupplierId = newSupplierId,
                            SectionId = section.Id 
                        };

                        var sectionSupplierJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(sectionSupplierDto);

                        var sectionSupplierResponse = await client.
                            PostAsync("https://localhost:7282/api/SectionSupliers/CreateSectionSupplier",
                            new StringContent(sectionSupplierJson, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));

                        await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("Supplier added Successfully", $"The Supplier {SupplierName} was added successfully with the Id {newSupplierId}", "Ok");
                        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"///{nameof(SupplierPage)}");
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("Error", ex.Message, "Ok");
            }
        }
```

but every time I run this command (by clicking a button) it gives me this exception:

> *No JSON Content found and type 'System.Int32' is not nullable . Path '', line 0, position 0*

Here are the controllers for  reference:

1. **The Supplier controller (just the HttpPost):**

```
[HttpPost("CreateSupplier")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<SupplierDto>> CreateSupplier(SupplierDto dto)
        {
            // Check if a supplier with the same name already exists
            if (await _context.Suppliers.AnyAsync(s => s.SupplierName == dto.SupplierName))
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("SupplierName", "A supplier with this name already exists.");
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            var supplier = new Supplier
            {
                SupplierName = dto.SupplierName,
                ReturnClause = dto.ReturnClause
            };

            _context.Suppliers.Add(supplier);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            var supplierResponse = new SupplierDto
            {
                Id = supplier.Id,
                SupplierName = dto.SupplierName,
                ReturnClause = dto.ReturnClause
            };

            return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetSupplier), new { id = supplier.Id }, supplierResponse);
        }
```

2. **The SectionSupplier Controller (Just the HttpPost):**

```
[HttpPost("CreateSectionSupplier")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<SectionSuplierDto>> CreateSectionSupplier(SectionSuplierDto dto)
        {
            if (await _context.SectionSupliers.AnyAsync(ss => ss.SectionId == dto.SectionId && ss.SupplierId == dto.SupplierId))
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("SectionId", "A SectionSupplier with this combination already exists.");
                ModelState.AddModelError("SupplierId", "A SectionSupplier with this combination already exists.");
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            var sectionSuplier = new SectionSuplier
            {
                SectionId = dto.SectionId,
                SupplierId = dto.SupplierId
            };

            _context.SectionSupliers.Add(sectionSuplier);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            var sectionSuplierResponse = new SectionSuplierDto
            {
                SectionId = sectionSuplier.SectionId,
                SupplierId = sectionSuplier.SupplierId
            };

            return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetSectionSuplier), sectionSuplierResponse);
        }
```

And here are the Models (or DTOs or data transfer objects because when creating the controllers I found a problem when using the Model so I ended up using like a copy of those models with only the data that I need):

**SupplierDto :**

```
public class SupplierDto
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "SupplierName is required.")]
        public string SupplierName { get; set; } = null!;
        public bool ReturnClause { get; set; }
    }
```

**SectionSupplierDto :**

```
public class SectionSuplierDto
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "SectionId is required.")]
        public int SectionId { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "SupplierId is required.")]
        public int SupplierId { get; set; }
    }
```

I tried debugging the `RelayCommand` but it wouldn't let me access it because it think that it throws an exception right at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out . It was Simple i just had to change the return type of the Controller of suppliers to return the id of the New added Supplier (which is an int) :

```
[HttpPost("CreateSupplier")]
    public async Task<int> CreateSupplier(SupplierDto dto)
    {
        // Check if a supplier with the same name already exists
        if (await _context.Suppliers.AnyAsync(s => s.SupplierName == dto.SupplierName))
        {
            return 0;
        }

        var supplier = new Supplier
        {
            SupplierName = dto.SupplierName,
            ReturnClause = dto.ReturnClause
        };

        _context.Suppliers.Add(supplier);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        var supplierResponse = new SupplierDto
        {
            Id = supplier.Id,
            SupplierName = dto.SupplierName,
            ReturnClause = dto.ReturnClause
        };

        return supplier.Id;
    }
```

And it worked